# How to solve for x in both Ax = B and Dx = C?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I understand how to solve for $Ax = B$ in Python using np.linalg.lstsq(), although when I test the $x$ matrix in another case, say $Dx = C$, the equality fails.

Here are the matrix shapes (since they aren't square):
$A$ and $D$ are 80 by 100,
$x$ is 100 by 1,
$B$ and $C$ are 80 by 1

I believe the solution not working for the second case is expected, although I need a solution for $x$ that will work with both cases, how would I go about finding this solution?

(and I do know a solution exists as $B$ and $C$ were created by multiplying $A$ and $D$ by a known $x$)

Comment: Gaussian elimination?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I can see how that can be used to solve the first equation, although I'm not sure how to find a solution for x that works with both equations

Comment: $Ax=B$ gives you $80$ equations in $100$ unknowns.  It should give a $20$ dimensional set of solutions, not just $1$.  $Dx=C$ applies $80$ more constraints, so your solution is overdetermined.  Unless the problem is carefully constructed there will be no solution.  You say it has been constructed to have a solution.  In that case you have $$\begin {pmatrix} A&0\\0&D \end {pmatrix} \begin {pmatrix} x\\x \end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix} B\\C \end {pmatrix}$$ to solve.  Your challenge is to get $$ \begin {pmatrix} x\\x \end {pmatrix}$$, which is a programming problem that can be solved math...

Comment: You can solve each and then search for the intersection of the affine spaces they determine.

Comment: I think the way to go about this is to “vertically stack” $A$ atop $D$ and $B$ atop $C$ and then try to find some approximate solution to the (overdetermined) system $\begin{pmatrix}A\\D\end{pmatrix}x = \begin{pmatrix}B\\C\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Joppy Thanks, that worked perfectly